# Is there a way to only read a certain field from Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a DB with a couple of levels deep nested stuff, sometimes pretty big.

now i have searched the doc and google/so, but couldn't find a simple answer:

if the schema is like:

```
{
    roomId      : String,
    created     : Date,
    teacher     : String,
    students    : Object,
    problems    : Array
}
```

is there a way to just read the `roomId` of every entry?
Not return the whole thing, but just an array of the `roomId`s?

(usecase: i want to make a list of all saved rooms, therefore i need absolutely nothing of all the other data, just the IDs. I want to avoid that overhead)

i'm pretty sure it can be done, but couldn't find how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/read-operations-introduction/#projections)

```
 Model.findOne({...}, {roomId: 1})....
```

Comment: oh well who could've known that's what they call it :D i guess that's the answer, thanks!
does this work with .find() and list them all?

Comment: NP. Please tick the answer, to save others some time